# How to move the modal box down

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to move the modal box itself lower in the screen. I saw a bunch of other answers but none of them worked.

```js
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");
modal.style.display = "block";
function closeModal() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
.modal {
  display: none; /* Hidden by default */
  z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
  padding-top: -600px; /* Location of the box */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

.modal-content {
    background-color: #fefefe;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 80%;
}
```

```html
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <h4 id="pHasNoBlock" style="font-family: 'Press Start 2P'">Did the robot pick up a block at the clicked location?</h4>
    <h4 id="pHasBlock" style="font-family: 'Press Start 2P'; display: none">Did the robot deliver a block at the highlighted location?</h4>
    <button class="modalButtonYes" onclick="closeModal()">Yes</button>
    <button class="modalButtonNo" onclick="closeModal()">No</button> 
  </div>
</div>
```

I tried using the padding-top element to lower it. This worked on w3schools, but not on my website itself. I am not sure if something else is conflicting or not.

Answer (score 1):

First off, `padding-top` is not allowed to have a negative value so it won't affect the position of your modal. Read more about `padding` at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding#Values).

If you want to position your modal further down on the page, try using `position:absolute` and set the desired distance from top in `px` :

```js
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");
modal.style.display = "block";
function closeModal() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
.modal {
  display: none; /* Hidden by default */
  z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
  left: 50px;
  top: 150px;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

.modal-content {
    background-color: #fefefe;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 80%;
}
```

```html
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <h4 id="pHasNoBlock" style="font-family: 'Press Start 2P'">Did the robot pick up a block at the clicked location?</h4>
    <h4 id="pHasBlock" style="font-family: 'Press Start 2P'; display: none">Did the robot deliver a block at the highlighted location?</h4>
    <button class="modalButtonYes" onclick="closeModal()">Yes</button>
    <button class="modalButtonNo" onclick="closeModal()">No</button> 
  </div>
</div>
```

If you increase or decrease the `top` value of the modal `class`, you will see its position move down and up respectively.

Comment: You should type `top: 50px;`

Comment: What @Steven said. Also `padding-top` is [not allowed to have a negative value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding#Values) so it won't actually do anything.

Comment: I tried it but it just made it weird by moving it to the left and not working.